# How can I push_back/copy custom type ( array) object to vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here is a fragment of my code in which I declare foo:

```
typedef pair<a, b> foo[8][8];
```

I wrote a function that copies objects of this type:

```
copy(foo1, foo2);
```

will copy foo2 to foo1. foo1 and foo2 are of type foo. Also, I have this vector:

```
vector<foo> lst;
```

I would like to have convenient access to it, i.e. `lst [0][0][0].first` would be an object of type a. How can I copy a foo object to this vector (lst)? I tried to do it this way:

```
lst.push_back( new foo );
copy(lst[lst.size() - 1], foo1);
```

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: you can't do this that way. to do that creat a class having custom default and cpy ctor at least and overload the operator `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<foo>` means "vector of foo values", you can't `push_back(new foo)` into it as `new foo` is a pointer (`foo*`). You'd need to `push_back(foo{})` which default-constructs a `foo` instance (a value). This doesn't work because:

- `std::vector<T>::push_back` [requires](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) that `T` is [MoveInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable) (in this particular case)
- `foo` is a C-array, and C-arrays are not *MoveInsertable*

In general, C-arrays don't work well with `std::vector`. You can use `std::array` instead, because it is *MoveInsertable*.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using foo = std::array<std::array<std::pair<float, float>, 8>, 8>;

std::vector<foo> v;
v.push_back(foo{});
std::cout << v[0][0][0].first << "\n";
```

In this case you don't need your `copy` function as `std::array` will do copying

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PcXWjXLxqMfEMQnB)